# Make slaves wait for MPI_Bcast from master

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to write a parallel program that implements a pipeline version of Gaussian elimination, using MPI and C language...

However I'm encountering some difficulties early in the implementation of the code....

I use a root process to read a data matrix from  a text file... this process gives-me the size of this matrix and I broadcast the size of it to all other processes in order for them to allocate it in memory... However, the slave processes are trying to allocate it before the broadcast from the root...
How can I make them wait?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int CalcInd(int i, int j, int dimL)
{
  return i*dimL +j;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *fin, *fout;
  char fA[] = "Matrix.txt";

  int rank, size, i, ii, j, k, m, n, picked, tmp, total;
  int  counter=0, elements=0;
  int * RightNeigbhor, * LeftNeigbhor, * loc;

  float f, magnitude, t;
  float * A, * x;

  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Request request;

  // MPI initialization
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);  
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if(rank == 0)
  {
    // Defenição dos processos vizinhos pelo master
    RightNeigbhor = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    if(RightNeigbhor==NULL)
      {printf("!!! Could not allocate memory !!!\n"); exit(-1);}
    LeftNeigbhor = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    if(RightNeigbhor==NULL)
      {printf("!!! Could not allocate memory !!!\n"); exit(-1);}

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
      RightNeigbhor[i] = (rank + 1) % size;
      LeftNeigbhor[i] = (rank - 1) % size;
    }
    // Broadcast os processos vizinhos para todos os processos
    MPI_Bcast ( RightNeigbhor, size, MPI_INTEGER, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    MPI_Bcast ( LeftNeigbhor, size, MPI_INTEGER, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    // Leitura da matriz A pelo master
    fin = fopen ( fA, "r" ); 
    if (fin == NULL){ printf("!!! FILE NOT FOUND !!!"); exit(-1); }
    while( !feof(fin))
    {
      fscanf (fin, "%f", &f);
      elements++;
    }
    rewind(fin);
    f = 0;

    while( !feof(fin))
    {
      if(fgetc(fin) == '\n')
      {
    counter++;
      }
    }
    rewind(fin);

    n = counter;
    m = (elements-1) / counter;

   total = n*m;   

   MPI_Bcast ( &total, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
   MPI_Bcast ( &n, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

  }

  // Alocação de variaveis
  A = (float *)calloc(total,sizeof(float));
  if(A==NULL){printf("!!! Could not allocate memory !!!\n"); exit(-1);}
  loc = (int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int*));
  if(loc==NULL){printf("!!! Could not allocate memory !!!\n"); exit(-1);}

// AND IT GOES ON AND ON
```

Comment: MPI_Bcast is a collective operation. Each rank should post MPI_Bcast in order for the operation to complete. Follow the suggestion from Bort.

Answer (score 4):

Everything in your `rank == 0` block runs only in process 0. While process `rank == 1 ... n` just skip that block. Therefore, you have to put your `MPI_Bcast` calls in an environment which is visible for all process in `MPI_Comm comm` here `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. When process 1...n skip all the initialization and jump to the broadcast before process 0 reaches it, they will wait till the bcast has occured.

Comment: So where exactly would the MPI_Bcast go? It seems if you put it before the if(rank==...) then all processes would do that task so can you specify exactly where in that script it would go?